# IE11 empty responses

Tags: reactjs, laravel, apache, axios

I've got an application with laravel 5 REST API and React 15 frontend ... I've used axios library for API calls ... I've got a problem only with IE11, I'm unable to login because of empty text response (I've looked on it in browser's console - network tab). The weird thing is that sometimes the authenticate call returns the right response with token, but the following api call which identifies the user is again empty ... I've made successful login after maybe 20 attempts (both authenticate and identify calls were successful with response text). I don't know where should I start to find some errors, anyone has some tips?

Comment: You're going to have to do some more debugging or give some code for context so we can try and reproduce the problem. Right now this question boils down to "something is wrong with my application" which doesn't give us enough to go on. What application? What's the scope of this problem? Does it impact all routes or just some? Just POST? GET? Anything?

Comment: @tadman I'm unable to login in IE11 only ... authenticate call is of type POST and it sometimes has empty response, sometimes not ... also identify api call (GET) ... I'm unable to test more api calls because I cant login.

Comment: You're going to have to identify how IE11 behaves differently from other browsers or there's nothing to go on here. Compare to Edge and Chrome for example.